# Class Handler instead of Object Handler

Tags: oop, design-patterns

What I have been taught, and therefor restricted to, is to pass an object as a handler. I have used this approach in both my Java and Objective-C programming projects, and it works.

However, I stumbled upon a framework that registers a class as the handler, not an object. I wish that framework was open-source so I can see how that works, but it isn't :/.

Beware! After I register the class, I implement **non-static** methods to handle the events. If they were static, it would be obvious how this works, and I would really hate this approach.

So, these are my questions:

- How does a class handler work and differ from *normal* object handlers?
- When would you recommend one over the other?
- Does this *pattern* have a name?

---

What I mean by object handlers:

**Java:**

```
button.addActionListener(handlerObject);
```

What I mean by class handlers:

**Java:**

```
object.addCrazyHandler(MyHandler.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java (not sure about Objective-C) allows you through the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to do introspection on objects and their classes, hence the `Object.getClass()` method and all the methods on [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Class.html). Not only can you find all the constructors, methods, fields, implemented interfaces and superclass of a class, you can also call them (though it's slower than a direct call): `newInstance()` on constructors, `invoke()` on methods, `get()` or `set()` on fields. For example (exception handlers omitted), to call a no-argument constructor through Reflection:

```
Object o = SomeClass.class.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Lots of frameworks use this: test frameworks such as [TestNG](http://testng.org/) or [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) use it to instanciate the test classes, for example. So does [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) when you use XML configuration.

In your case, I suppose the framework wants to control the lifecycle of the handler, which it can't if you provide it with an instance. Another option would have been for it to take an instance of a factory, but that may be too restrictive. That can also mean more boiler-plate code to write, when it can easily create the object itself.

Comment: I haven't seen this in Objective-C TBH, but it looks like it can easily be applied. "the framework wants to control the lifecycle of the handler", you really nailed it there.